# cannot find module './framer' after deleting node modules

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I was cleaning up the angular code and, deleted some unused custom modules. After which, It was throwing an error about a deleted imported component in app.module.ts even though it was already removed from import.

Then, I manually deleted the node modules, ran npm install and tried to run npm start which gives me the following error:

```
  Cannot find module './framer'
  Error: Cannot find module './framer'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NBS627\eclipse-workspace\ccmobile- 
   UI\node_modules\spdy-transport\lib\spdy-transport\protocol\base\index.js:7:18)
   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\NBS627\eclipse-workspace\ccmobile- 
   UI\node_modules\spdy-transport\lib\spdy-transport.js:10:27)
   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
```

I have no idea about this error. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error says that you have a problem with your `spdy-transport` module.

To solve this you must update your `spdy-transport` module:

```
npm un spdy-transport
```

Then:

```
npm i spdy-transport
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the packages which you deleted might have a dependency on an existing module

for example, when we do `npm install package-name`, often more than one folder are created in the node_modules folder, we may think that it is not required but it is in fact needed

Comment: I fear that you might get a lot of these... where every time the culprit would be different, Dhawal in his comment below got you started, this is how you would have to uninstall and reinstall packages one by one... the reason remains the same as in my answer

Comment: As you said, Dhawal's answer solved my above issue and has moved on to next issue. At least, I am not stuck any more!